# Unity Admob and Google Play Game Services Build Error

Tags: c#, admob, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have been struggling to understand how to fix the error: "Failed to repackage resources" I cannot seem to get my application to build when I have both the AdMob unity plugin installed and Google Play Game Plugin. I am using Unity Unity 5.6.1f1 (64-bit).

game services: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity Ads: https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

It works fine till I add the google play game services plugin. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The relevant part of the error I believe:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
 C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Jack/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.unity.purchasing:com.android.vending.billing:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4 -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\common\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.6\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.2.0\res"

 stderr[
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:48: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:77: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:96: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:64: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_lines for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:43: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <include>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:33: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_media for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <Chronometer>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_part_chronometer for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <DateTimeView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/notification_template_part_time for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material for configuration v17.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:drawable/abc_ratingbar_indicator_material for configuration v21.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.jrfapplications.psychorunner:drawable/abc_ratingbar_small_material for configuration v21.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:33: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:34: Original attribute defined here.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:46: error: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible format.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:47: Original attribute defined here.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:54: error: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with incompatible format.
 E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:55: Original attribute defined here.
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually indicates you have multiple versions of the support-v4-*.aar file in Assets/Plugins/Android (or a subdirectory).

I recommend keeping the greatest version of the support library and delete the older versions.

Comment: I have installed fresh copied of both plugin and in my plugins folder I have have one copy of support-v4 which is **support-v4-25.2.0** thanks for your response

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction the error has gone away after removing duplicate aar files but I have new error. Thanks for guidence

Answer (score 0):

> E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:33:
>   error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with
>   incompatible format.  E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:34:
>   Original attribute defined here.  E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho
>   Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:46:
>   error: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible
>   format.  E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:47:
>   Original attribute defined here.  E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho
>   Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:54:
>   error: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with incompatible
>   format.  E:\JRFApplications\Apps\Psycho Dash\Psycho
>   Dash\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\res\values\values.xml:55:
>   Original attribute defined here.

The issue can be seen in the last part of the log. You can see that you have the same library twice (play-services-base) with different versions - one is 10.2.0 and the other is 10.2.6.

This will create conflicts that will prevent you from building your APK.

You should eliminate these duplicates before building.